# Which Cocoa Touch control is this (screenshot)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm seeing these all over the place but I'm wondering what controls are used here?

1. What is the thing with the arrow pointing right? Is it a UIRoundRectButton with a ">" (greater than) character?
2. What is the box with the rounded corners below which allows separaring content using a horzontal line? Also looks like a button...

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just setting the proper accessory type: [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Go to accessory type there.

Comment: So each of these round cornered boxed is a table cell? That's it?